# Can't acces admin account, how may I fix it?

Tags: 13.10

So when I try to log into the admin account i go right back to the log-in screen. And I've been searching around all over the internet trying to fix it, but then some other problems always comes along, how may I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The administrative user in Unix systems is 'root'.  It is safest if you log in as an ordinary user and use the `sudo` command from the terminal to run commands with root privileges.  That way, you are less able to accidentally damage your system.  Unlike Windows, Unix commands really are normally run as an ordinary user, and some commands even refuse to run if you are root.

Usually, Ctrl+Alt+T will start a terminal.  In the terminal, pre-pend your administrative command with `sudo`, for example `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  If you have a long sequence of commands to run as root, you can use `sudo bash -login` to run a login shell.  Then you no longer need to put `sudo` in front of each command.  Type `exit` or hit Ctrl+D to leave the root-enabled shell.

Comment: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/504769/cant-acces-admin-account-how-may-i-fix-it" that's what I get when I try to use commands (I'm on the guest account)

Comment: sorry, i get this "unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted"

Comment: "unable to change..." means you are logged into an account without access to the "sudo" group.  Can you reboot the machine as in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)?

Another option is to remove the hard drive from the computer, mount it on a different computer, and edit the file `/etc/group`, so that you add your user name to the "sudo" line, something like: `sudo:x:27:yourlogin,anotherlogin`.